# Не могу создать заказ через апи мой склад

Tags: yii2, мойсклад-api

На сайте используется апи мой склад. Пока только товары брались с него и все. Клиент захотел, что бы оформленный заказ на сайте сразу летел в мой склад.

Использую этот плагин - [апи мой склад](https://github.com/Tooyz/moysklad)

Вот код, которым я пытаюсь создать заказ

```
$order = (new CustomerOrder($sklad))->buildCreation()
        ->addCounterparty($counterparty)
        ->addOrganization($organization)
        ->addPositionList($position)
        ->execute();
```

И я столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу правильно сформировать массив ***$position***. Я думал, что надо как то так

```
$position[] = Product::query($sklad)->byId('3ce0cfc2-5d23-11e8-9ff4-34e800155763');
```

Но нет, получаю ошибку

```
Argument 1 passed to MoySklad\Components\MutationBuilders\AbstractMutationBuilder::addPositionList() must be an instance of MoySklad\Lists\EntityList, array given, called
```

Может кто сталкивался, помогите.

Comment: Вам же написано в ошибке, что должен быть не массив а объект класса MoySklad\Lists\EntityList

Comment: Проблема в том, что у этого апи нету такого класса

Comment: @Diefair как нету, вот он https://github.com/Tooyz/moysklad/blob/master/src/Lists/EntityList.php

Comment: @Diefair метод [addPositionList](https://github.com/Tooyz/moysklad/blob/master/src/Components/MutationBuilders/AbstractMutationBuilder.php#L638) требует свормированный объект `EntityList`, который как раз принимает массив `items` и другие параметры в конструкторе

Comment: класс нашел, спасибо. теперь вопрос в том, что надо передавать в EntityList? я делаю так - new EntityList($sklad, [Product::query($sklad)->byId('3ce0cfc2-5d23-11e8-9ff4-34e800155763')]); - и не работает

Comment: и так правильно, но теперь я получаю ошибку, что не указано Способ отправки и количество. вопрос: где их указать?

Comment: @Diefair документация немного унылая, но вот этот кусок думаю поможет [EntityList - обертка для массива для работы с апи](https://github.com/Tooyz/moysklad#%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Comment: $position = new EntityList($sklad, [["quantity" => 1,"assortment" => ["meta" => ["href" =>"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/3ce0cfc2-5d23-11e8-9ff4-34e800155763","type" => "product","mediaType" => "application/json"]]]]);

Comment: пробую так, не выходит, говорит Argument 1 passed to MoySklad\Components\MutationBuilders\AbstractMutationBuilder::MoySklad\Components\MutationBuilders\{closure}() must be an instance of MoySklad\Entities\Products\AbstractProduct, array given

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$productsArr = [];
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $quantity = $product['Quantity'];
    $price = $product['Price'];
    $code = $product['Code'];

    $productItem = Product::query($sklad)->byId($filteredProduct->id);

    $productItem->quantity = (int) $quantity;
    $productItem->price = (int) $price;
    $productsArr[] = $productItem;

}

$productsArr = new EntityList($sklad, $productsArr);

$co = (new CustomerOrder($sklad, [
    "name" => "TestOrder 111",
    "moment" => "2016-04-19 13:50:24"
]))
    ->buildCreation()
    ->addCounterparty($userMC)
    ->addOrganization($org)
    ->addPositionList($productsArr)
    ->execute();
```

**Очень важно чтобы quantity и price были числами!**